# Is there any way to reduce the opacity of a MUI palette element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a component that create a "marker" with a color as a props.

```
<ColoredMarker color="primary.main">
  I'm supposed to be purple
</ColoredMarker>
```

The color is used as a color for the font and as the background's but with an opacity of 0.1.

My problem is that while I'm handling hex values (taking r,g,b and returning an rgba(r,g,b,0.1), I also want to be able to handle elements from my palette.

I tried doing it using the alpha() function but since there is no documentation about it and that it's not working, I suppose it's the wrong way.

So is there any way that I could reduce its opacity ? Or maybe get the color value of the palette element and THEN apply a 0.1 opacity ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried inline? you can use the rgb values that used to create the theme color and use like this. But I know that is a long way process, but that is the only way I solved my issue which was same as yours.

```html
<Box backgroundColor= 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'> 
Your Content Here.... 
</Box>
```